# How to invoke Stata and run syntax via R?

Tags: r, stata, reporters

I have an odd situation, and please pardon me for not providing a reproducible example for this question. I have more than 1000 lines of syntax written for Stata to carry out multiple analyses (I wrote it before I started using R). This syntax is used to perform analysis in a quarterly dataset every 3 months to create a report. Results of the analyses are saved in csv files, and read via R, and put into a Word document using ReporterS package.

Is there any way to invoke Stata via R, and specify/pipe the syntax to run it? (I understand the reverse situation can be done using `rsource` (user-written command) in Stata). I can still manually fire up Stata and run the syntax there. But is it possible to do it via R? So, a shiny app/web interface can be created to do this part, and the user doesn't need to do it manually?

Comment: You can run Stata in batch mode - http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/windows/batch-mode/ - As such you could use R's `system` calls to run Stata and a specified .do file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah that solution would work nicely. I have used `system` numerous times, but it didn't spark in my mind when I was looking for an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @thelatemail suggests, the easiest thing to do here is simply run Stata [in batch mode](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/windows/batch-mode/) from a `system` call.

Here's an example do file (called `"example.do"`):

```
log using out.log, replace
sysuse auto
regress mpg weight foreign
```

And here's the R code to run it and retrieve the output (assuming Stata is on your path and you replace `Stata-64` with the appropriate binary file on your machine):

```
> system("Stata-64 /e do example.do"); readLines("out.log")
 [1] "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
 [2] "      name:  <unnamed>"                                                                                                 
 [3] "       log:  FilePathHere"                                                                     
 [4] "  log type:  text"                                                                                                      
 [5] " opened on:   9 Jan 2015, 13:34:18"                                                                                     
 [6] ""                                                                                                                       
 [7] ". sysuse auto"                                                                                                          
 [8] "(1978 Automobile Data)"                                                                                                 
 [9] ""                                                                                                                       
[10] ". regress mpg weight foreign"                                                                                           
[11] ""                                                                                                                       
[12] "      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74"                                         
[13] "-------------+------------------------------           F(  2,    71) =   69.75"                                         
[14] "       Model |   1619.2877     2  809.643849           Prob > F      =  0.0000"                                         
[15] "    Residual |  824.171761    71   11.608053           R-squared     =  0.6627"                                         
[16] "-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.6532"                                         
[17] "       Total |  2443.45946    73  33.4720474           Root MSE      =  3.4071"                                         
[18] ""                                                                                                                       
[19] "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"                                         
[20] "         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]"                                         
[21] "-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------"                                         
[22] "      weight |  -.0065879   .0006371   -10.34   0.000    -.0078583   -.0053175"                                         
[23] "     foreign |  -1.650029   1.075994    -1.53   0.130      -3.7955    .4954422"                                         
[24] "       _cons |    41.6797   2.165547    19.25   0.000     37.36172    45.99768"                                         
[25] "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"                                         
[26] ""                                                                                                                       
[27] ". "                                                                                                                     
[28] "end of do-file"                                                                                                         
[29] ""                                                                                                                       
[30] ". exit, clear"
```

It may be easier to parse the output if you log using Stata Markup Control Language (SMCL), by replacing the first line of the do file with `log using out.log, replace smcl`. Then the output will be:

```
 [1] "{smcl}"                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [2] "{com}{sf}{ul off}{txt}{.-}"                                                                                                                                                             
 [3] "      name:  {res}<unnamed>"                                                                                                                                                            
 [4] "       {txt}log:  {res}FilePathHere"                                                                                                                        
 [5] "  {txt}log type:  {res}smcl"                                                                                                                                                            
 [6] " {txt}opened on:  {res} 9 Jan 2015, 13:41:53"                                                                                                                                           
 [7] "{txt}"                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [8] "{com}. sysuse auto"                                                                                                                                                                     
 [9] "{txt}(1978 Automobile Data)"                                                                                                                                                            
[10] ""                                                                                                                                                                                       
[11] "{com}. regress mpg weight foreign"                                                                                                                                                      
[12] ""                                                                                                                                                                                       
[13] "      {txt}Source {c |}       SS       df       MS              Number of obs ={res}      74"                                                                                           
[14] "{txt}{hline 13}{char +}{hline 30}           F(  2,    71) ={res}   69.75"                                                                                                               
[15] "    {txt}   Model {char |} {res}  1619.2877     2  809.643849           {txt}Prob > F      = {res} 0.0000"                                                                              
[16] "    {txt}Residual {char |} {res} 824.171761    71   11.608053           {txt}R-squared     = {res} 0.6627"                                                                              
[17] "{txt}{hline 13}{char +}{hline 30}           Adj R-squared = {res} 0.6532"                                                                                                               
[18] "    {txt}   Total {char |} {res} 2443.45946    73  33.4720474           {txt}Root MSE      = {res} 3.4071"                                                                              
[19] ""                                                                                                                                                                                       
[20] "{txt}{hline 13}{c TT}{hline 11}{hline 11}{hline 9}{hline 8}{hline 13}{hline 12}"                                                                                                        
[21] "{col 1}         mpg{col 14}{c |}      Coef.{col 26}   Std. Err.{col 38}      t{col 46}   P>|t|{col 54}     [95% Con{col 67}f. Interval]"                                                
[22] "{hline 13}{c +}{hline 11}{hline 11}{hline 9}{hline 8}{hline 13}{hline 12}"                                                                                                              
[23] "{space 6}weight {c |}{col 14}{res}{space 2}-.0065879{col 26}{space 2} .0006371{col 37}{space 1}  -10.34{col 46}{space 3}0.000{col 54}{space 4}-.0078583{col 67}{space 3}-.0053175"      
[24] "{txt}{space 5}foreign {c |}{col 14}{res}{space 2}-1.650029{col 26}{space 2} 1.075994{col 37}{space 1}   -1.53{col 46}{space 3}0.130{col 54}{space 4}  -3.7955{col 67}{space 3} .4954422"
[25] "{txt}{space 7}_cons {c |}{col 14}{res}{space 2}  41.6797{col 26}{space 2} 2.165547{col 37}{space 1}   19.25{col 46}{space 3}0.000{col 54}{space 4} 37.36172{col 67}{space 3} 45.99768"  
[26] "{txt}{hline 13}{c BT}{hline 11}{hline 11}{hline 9}{hline 8}{hline 13}{hline 12}"                                                                                                        
[27] "{res}{txt}"                                                                                                                                                                             
[28] "{com}. "                                                                                                                                                                                
[29] "{txt}end of do-file"
```